How to change dropdown text for all dropdown menu if one changed in laravel
I am New to Laravel and learning the coding from YouTube.
Here i am working on one home project where having 4 dropdown menu showing duration ( current month, last month etc ) with 4 graph which changed as per selected.
If u changed the duration from one dropdown, all 4 graph changed but dropdown menu selected item remain same which need to change.
code as per follow for one dropdown - same used for all 4 menu.
<div class="btn-group col-1 d-grid d-md-flex justify-content-end">
                  <button type="button" style="color:black;height:30px" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs mb-0 shadow-sm dropdown-button" id="dropdownmenuselect" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">FY - {{$financial_year}}</button>
                  <ul id='avgcost' class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="get_data('currentmonth')">{{$getcurrentmonthname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="get_data('lastsixmonth')">{{$getcurrentmonthname}} to {{$getlastsixmonthname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="get_data('financialyear')">FY - {{$financial_year}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="get_data('lastfinancialyear')">FY - {{$last_financial_year}}</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

function for onclick event
function get_data(duration) {

  // Drop Down Button Text Chnage

    $('.dropdown-toggle')
      .next('.dropdown-menu')
      .children()
      .on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').prev('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text());
      });

       //ajax run from where

});

Thanks in Advance..
If u changed the duration from one dropdown, all 4 graph changed but dropdown menu selected item remain same which need to change.
